# Why is position sticky not working as expected?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm having some problems trying to identify why in this snippet the `container__item--special` behaves as a sticky element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: flex;
                overflow-x: auto;
                position: relative;
            }

            .container__item {
                width: 200px;
                height: 50px;
                border: 1px solid;
                flex-shrink: 0;
            }

            .container__item--special {
                position: sticky;
                left: 0; 
                background-color: red;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container__item"></div>
            <div class="container__item"></div>
            <div class="container__item container__item--special"></div>
            <div class="container__item"></div>
            <div class="container__item"></div>
            <div class="container__item"></div>
            <div class="container__item"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But in here it doesn't

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                overflow-x: auto;
                position: relative;
            }

            .sub-container {
                display: flex;
            }

            .container__item {
                width: 200px;
                height: 50px;
                border: 1px solid;
                flex-shrink: 0;
            }

            .container__item--special {
                position: sticky;
                left: 0; 
                background-color: red;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="sub-container">
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item container__item--special"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-container">
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `container__item--special` element in your second example is sticky in relation to its parent container - `sub-container`. That parent container doesn't have an internal scroll, so the `sticky` element will never "stick" since it's position within its parent doesn't change. So, the "sticky" element in the second example is working exactly as expected.

Comment: @disinfor sub-container doesn't need any internal scroll for sticky to works. It's actually a width issue due to a default stretch alignment

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah, I was looking at it as if the two `sub-containers` were side by side. Looking at your example, it makes sense to why it wasn't "working".

Answer (score 1):

Add some border to the parent element to understand what is happening:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.container__item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container__item--special {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item container__item--special"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have a little space for the sticky behavior because the parent is limited to its parent width due to the stretch default alignment. Disable it and it will work as you like

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-container {
  display: flex;
  align-self: start; /* added */
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.container__item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container__item--special {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item container__item--special"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please review below updated code where only the CSS in the "sub-container" and "container" class needs modification. You just need to add "container" class css to "sub-container" class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
          .container {
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
          }
          .sub-container {
              display: flex;
              overflow-x: auto;
              position: relative;
          }

          .container__item {
              width: 200px;
              height: 50px;
              border: 1px solid;
              flex-shrink: 0;
          }

          .container__item--special {
              position: sticky;
              left: 0; 
              background-color: red;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="container">
             <div class="sub-container">
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item container__item--special"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-container">
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
                <div class="container__item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please update here if this works for you.